# Authentication not working anymore as I'm developing

Tags: php, authentication, symfony4

I followed the security guide to setup users authentication, and it worked perfectly. Then I wen on, customized the login form and I'm not able to login again.

tried to put a die('test') as first line of login authenticator but not working. Also, I don't get how it worked before, as the form tag has no action (same on symfony guide thou).

this is my login authenticator:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request->request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];

        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['username']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['username']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Username could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {;
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']) && $user->getEnabled();
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        // redirect to some "app_homepage" route - of wherever you want
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('/'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');
    }
}
```

and this is my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center login">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-center">Please sign in</h1>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
                                {% if error %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
                                {% endif %}

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                                        <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                                        <input type="text" value="{{ last_username }}" name="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                                        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-5">
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="_remember_me">
                                            <label>{% trans %}Remember me{% endtrans %}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-5">
                                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

any help?
thanks

Comment: in Symfony 4 im pretty sure the name of username and password has to have an underscore: _username _password

Comment: Please enable error reporting including notices and warnings or log into the look for errors. Guessing is off-topic on SO.